# How do I include page-specific JavaScript?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In my Rails app, every page includes all of the JavaScripts in `assets`.

Some custom scripts are for Ajax and some fancy stuff. which run unnecessarily from every page and are causing me unnecessary overload.

For example, the session page doesn't really need any JavaScript at all, still all scripts are included. How do I change this? I have Rails 3.2.2.

```
<script src="/assets/jquery-1.7.2.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.ui.core.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.ui.widget.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.ui.position.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.ui.autocomplete.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/special.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: If your web server is properly returning caching headers for your scripts, note that it doesn't hurt to have them 'loaded' for pages that don't need them. Indeed, most of my sites use a single minified JavaScript file included on every page of the site, and that JavaScript file conditionally executes code based on which page it is on.

Comment: We have published a gem that resolves this issue, check the blog post http://eng.wolox.com.ar/blog/2013/04/19/introducing-loadjs/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I use `content_for`.

#### application.html.erb

```
<head>
  <%= yield :custom_js %>
</head>
```

#### your_page.html.erb

```
<% content_for :custom_js do %>
   <!-- your script includes go here -->
<% end %>
```

Comment: Tried that. Seems like my pages are including all scripts in the asset folder, even though I took them out from `application.js`. all scripts are loaded.

Comment: Look for `require_tree` in the application.js, this is what is loading them.

Answer (score 2):

Don't put the `<script>` elements in your layout, put them on the page(s) you need. Alternatively, have your layout conditionally include them based on logic set in your controller.