# How to include action specific CSS or JS in Rails 3.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, asset-pipeline

I build a website using Rails 3.2.9 and the [twitter-bootstrap-rails](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails) gem.

I understand that Rails Asset Pipeline merges all the CSS into one file. I wonder, however, how easy it is to modify this behavior (not sure if this is a good idea).

Suppose I have a `Site` controller with two actions: `home` and `contact_us`, and there are the following CSS:

- `site.css.scss` - should be loaded in **every action** of `Site` controller
- `home.css.scss` - should be loaded only in `home` action of `Site` controller
- `contact_us.css.scss` - should be loaded only in `contact_us` action of `Site` controller

How would you achieve this?

Comment: A solution for javascript that can be used for CSS as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10656407/how-do-i-include-page-specific-javascript

Answer (score 2):

I don't think splitting it out for different page loads is a good idea. In production mode everything comes in one file, so ALL your CSS only needs to be loaded once. So every subsequent page load won't load it again.
It's not just about size, it's about how many connections and requests to your webserver. Less is often better.

However if you really want to, you can have a conditional tag in the head section of your template.

```
stylesheet_link_tag 'home' if controller.action_name == 'home'
stylesheet_link_tag 'contact_us' if controller.action_name == 'contact_us'
```

You can also get the controller name with `controller.controller_name`

Answer (score 0):

> I understand that Rails Asset Pipeline merges all the CSS into one file. I wonder, however, how easy it is to modify this behavior (not sure if this is a good idea).

I don't think it's a good idea as you would lost the benefit of fetching the CSS file only once. I am not sure that's the goal you are after but you wouldn't save any server resources, creating additional request for a specific file is kinda expensive.

Anyway, you can do it by not requiring the tree of files in you application.css.scss (or create a specific folder) and then manually calling stylesheet_link_tag (you should probably combine this with content_for helper so that you can say where exactly you want to like to appear, see [Using the content_for Method](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-the-content_for-method))